# How to Deploy a Laravel Project Locally

Tags: laravel, deployment, web-deployment

Hi I have an exchange project developed in laravel and I want to deploy it locally for 1 or 2 pc basically sometimes it is one pc what is the efficient way to deploy it for end-user in my case end-user is not educated that much to start laravel artisan server and so on Thanks in Advance.
I use Wamp for apche and mysql

Comment: Could you just php artisan serve command. I know you are used to wamp, but this would be running on your local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use xampp if windows. And set it to auto run on lauch and boot so there will be no user interaction required. And use the vhost configuration of apache inside xampp to make the laravel project available to everyone.

You can edit the VHost file located in xampp/apache/conf/extra

Now add this line to the very bottom of the file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot “C:/xampp/htdocs/yourProject”
DirectoryIndex index.php
ServerName laravel-gkb.test
<Directory “C:/xampp/htdocs/yourProject/public”>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In the example above, “yourProject” is the folder of your project and you can change the path of your project. Normally you’d put the project folder in htdocs folder located inside xampp folder. The “*” is just telling that this should be accessible through the machines IP address and it is pointing to the projects public folder where the index.php (main index) file is located. So now if you write your machines IP, it should technically run your application. Read on how to install and setup xampp [here](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)

Goodluck

**Update**

If the users are not that experienced to run artisan serve command, write a bat file in windows which will allow them to run the serve command and keep the project in one pc so everyone can access the project using that machines IP. If for some reason you’re not able to access the IP, check firewall options. Install php, register it in path/environment of windows and write a bat file which will look something like this (warning. Not tested):

```
@echo off
php artisan serve —host=192.168.1.101 —port=8000
```

Now save the file as .bat file and you can run this file to run serve. Host is the machines IP. You can set a static IP for that machine if you don’t want it to change. And port you can set to whatever you want. This is just an alternative. Howevet, I would still go for wamp or xampp

Comment: I it possible with wamp

Comment: Yes it is possible with wamp as well. Almost the same procedure. Follow their installation guides

Comment: in case of wamp or xamp should i run the command artisan any time and keep it on also?

Comment: and what i should write on my browser to receive the files 404  occurs when i try

Comment: No when using wamp or xampp you just need to run wamp or xampps apache and mysql servers. Please elaborate what you mean by 404. You are probably writing a route/url which does not exist. Please read the documentation on how to deploy laravel with xampp or wamp

Answer (score -2):

Well, i think you can use Xampp, start Apache server for your local network,
put your project inside and you can acces it for wathever pc you have in the same network.
I have the project in this route: C:\xampp\htdocs\LARAVEL\App01
If you execute xampp and puts the next url: http://localhost/LARAVEL/App01/server.php/NameController
That's work, without using serve, you dont need serve. That form you are starting xampp (Apache) Server for local network.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V46fm.png)

Comment: but how to start laravel artisan server

Comment: I have the project in this route: